# Elastic IP Not Resolving to Windows Instance

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, web-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip

I'm sure I'm just missing a step, but I can't figure out how to get server to resolve to new elastic IP address. I appreciate everyone for their help. I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and can't seem to get it.

This is the response for IP Address 2 when typing IP directly into the browser (New Elastic IP Address)

[image]

This is the correct response that I'm getting with IP Address 1

[image]

Here's the settings for my instance. As you can see it has IP Address 1 as the public and elastic IP addresses:

[image]

Here's the security settings for "WebServerSG" security group.

[image]

And here's the elastic IP settings where you can see that IP Address 2 is set to the VPC and the instance and also you can see the private IP address that's referenced as the secondary IP addresses field of my instance details.

[image]

Comment: Did you restart the server/IIS after assigning a second IP address? IIS won't automatically listen on additional IPs unless you restart it.

Comment: Yes, I have the default website in IIS setup to listen to all IP addresses. It has been restarted since this change occurred.

Comment: How have you associated address 2 with your instance?

Comment: Sorry, somehow my final pic didn't get put into post. See the last pic now. Both IP addresses are associated with the same instance.